# Is it appropriate to fix factual errors without the author's "permission"?

Tags: support, editing

When browsing answers, occasionally you will find an answer a very good answer that has a factually incorrect statement in it. I have always operated under the philosophy that we want to stay true to the intent of an author's answer, but that it's unlikely they intended to be factually incorrect. If the comments yield a consensus that the statement is indeed incorrect and should be fixed (that is to say, the error isn't so detrimental to the answer that you should abandon the answer and create a new one), what would be the most appropriate action to take?

1. Make the edit (or suggested edit if you lack the reputation).
2. Leave a comment for the author to make the edit.
3. Downvote and explain the downvote is because of the error and what needs to be fixed.
4. Something else I'm not thinking of.

Naturally, I've usually done the first option on Stack Exchange, but I want to make sure that I follow the same kinds of protocols the Physics site does when I'm browsing questions here.

*I apologize if I'm "leading the question" because of my opinion that the first option is the correct one. I tried to make the question as neutral as possible, but bias always slips through. =(*